# Call method when changing UITextField's directly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I'm currently developing an iPhone app where I have two UITextField's in one View Controller.
I have a method that is called when the keyboard appears (`keyboardWillShow`), and one that is called when it disappears (`keyboardWillDisappear`).

Now if the user touches the first field the `keyboardWillShow` method is called, but if he now touches the second field without touching the background before, `keyboardWillShow` of course is not called again, because the keyboard is already here.
I can also not use `textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` because it's also not called when you change field's directly.

Now how can i call `keyboardWillShow` again if he touches the first and the second one without letting the keyboard disappear between??

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the delegate properly for the second text field? Because `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` *should* get called.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Forgot to do that... :)

Comment: If that's the fix, please post it as a reply and accept so everyone knows it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was i didn't set the delegate of the textfield's properly.

After setting `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`in my .h file and `textfield2.delegate = self` in the .m file, `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` was called when i changed the textfield's directly.